# How to bind nested ItemsControl ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection nested within parent ItemControl's bound item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an `ItemsControl` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. Inside of that `ItemsControl` I have another `ItemsControl` which is bound to another `ObservableCollection` contained within the objects of the outermost `ItemsControl`'s ObservableCollection.  When the XAML parser attempts to build the innermost `ItemsControl`'s `DataTemplate` there is an exception thrown

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Add value to collection of
>   type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.

and the inner exception is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while
>   ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with
>   ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

To make it a little more clear, here is my XAML Structure:

```
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ...Name of object holding ObservableCollection here}">
        <ItemsControl Name="FilterItemsHolder" Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Margin="10,10,10,10" MinWidth="200"
                  Background="#151515"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CheckedFilterColumns}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MaxHeight="100">
                        <ItemsControl Name="FilterSelectionsHolder"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  Margin="10,10,10,10" MaxHeight="50"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding FilterSelections}">
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <rb:RBFilterOptions x:Name="FilterOptions" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

The class structure of the DataBound items is:

```
public class ClassThatHoldsCollections...
{
    ... some other properties
    public ObservableCollection<RBDataColumn> CheckedFilterColumns { get; set; } //bound to outermost ItemsControl's (Name="FilterItemsHolder") ItemsSource

    public ClassThatHoldsCollections...()
    {
        ...initialize property values...
        CheckedFilterColumns = new ObservableCollection<RBDataColumn>();
    }
}
public class RBDataColumn
{
    ...some properties

    public ObservableCollection<RBDataColumnFilterSelection> FilterSelections { get; set; } //bound to innermost ItemsControl's (Name="FilterSelectionsHolder") ItemsSource

    public RBDataColumn()
    {
        ...initialize property values...
        FilterSelections = new ObservableCollection<RBDataColumnFilterSelection>();
    }
}
```

Oddly enough if I comment out the `<DataTemplate>...</DataTemplate>` the exception is no longer thrown.  If I leave the `<DataTemplate></DataTemplate>` tags and comment out only the referenced user control within `<rb:RBFilterOptions.../>` the exception is still thrown which means that it cannot be the underlying user control that is causing the issue.

It seems to me that the XAML parser that builds the window is trying to add the inner `ItemsControl`'s values while still accessing the outermost `ItemsControl`'s.

**MY QUESTION, IN TWO PARTS, IS:**

1. Why is the exception thrown?
2. Is there a way to have nested `ItemsControl`s whose `ItemsSource` properties are pointed to nested `ObservableCollections`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the error message i.e. there's something wrong with your XAML. Specifically, you've declared your inner `DataTemplate` as a direct child of `FilterSelectionsHolder`, so the XAML parser thinks you're adding it as a collection item rather than a template. Try wrapping the inner `DataTemplate` in a `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` block.

Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes. ;)

Comment: Incredible, I can't believe I didn't notice that! Thanks for the help, I'm sure this will fix the problem. I have been beating my head against the wall for hours on this.